# Show "All", "Multiple" or "one" based on number of dropdown selections in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I have a checkbox list of locations which comes up in a pop-up allowing them to select one, multiple or all location. The default label of dropdown is "**Select Locations**".

How do I handle following scenarios:

1. Display "**All**" in the dropdown selection if user selects "**select all**" from the list.
2. Display "**Multiple**"  if user selects **more than one** location.
3. Display "**location name**" if user selects **only one** location.

Here is the code that I am using to create dropdown and pop-up for list, but currently it displays only "Select Location(s)" no matter what user selects from dropdown.

```
 <div class="dropdown cp-dropdown">
        <div class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <!-- {{homeCtrl.newActivitySelectedLocation === '' ? 'Select Location' : homeCtrl.newActivitySelectedLocation.Name}}-->
            Select Location(s)
      

            <span class="pull-right caret"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="location-list" class="dropdown-menu cp-checkbox-dropdown menu-container" role="menu" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();">
            <div>
                <input type="text" ng-model="homeCtrl.newActivitySearchLocation" />
            </div>
            <div id="location-list-container">
                <div class="row" ng-if="homeCtrl.newActivityLocationList.length > 0">
                    <label class="cp-checkbox">
                        <input value="ALL" type="checkbox" id="select_all_locpop" ng-model="homeCtrl.newActivityLocationSelectAll" ng-click="homeCtrl.newActivityLocationFilter('All', homeCtrl.newActivityLocationSelectAll)" />
                        <span></span>Select All
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div id="location-list-pop">
                    <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="location in homeCtrl.newActivityLocationList | filter: {'Name':homeCtrl.newActivitySearchLocation}">
                        <label class="cp-checkbox">
                            <input value="{{location.Id}}" type="checkbox" ng-click="homeCtrl.updateActivityGrid('location-list-pop','select_all_locpop')" /><span></span>
                            {{location.Name}}
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your **dropdown**? Please, clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your clicks in a temp list and update the label depending on the status between the main list and the temp.

```
var  updateLocationDisplay = function(){

  if(tempList.length === mainList.length){
    $scope.locationLabel = "All";
  }else if(tempList.length > 1){
    $scope.locationLabel = "Multiple";
  }else if(tempList.length === 1){
    $scope.locationLabel = tempList[0];
  }else{
    $scope.locationLabel = "Select a location";
  }
};

$scope.locationClick = function(name){
   var index = tempList.indexOf(name);
   if(index > 0){
     // remove it
     tempList.splice(index, 1);   
    }
   else{
    // add it
     tempList.push(name);
  }

   updateLocationDisplay();
 };
```

}